# How to change the menu link color when the link is opened in iframe?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="navi">
<ul width="100%" align="center" style="padding-top:20px; display:inline">
<li>    
<a style="font-size:25px; color:#0ff; padding-top:20px;    font-weight:bold;" href="corporate_frame.html" target="load">Corporate</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</li>   
<li>    
<a style="font-size:25px; color:#0ff; font-weight:bold"  href="security_frame.html" target="load">Security</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</li>   
<li>
<a style="font-size:25px; color:#0ff; font-weight:bold" href="driver_frame.html" target="load">Driver</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</li>   
<li>
<a style="font-size:25px; color:#0ff; font-weight:bold" href="medical_frame.html" target="load">Medical</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</li>
<li>
<a style="font-size:25px; color:#0ff; font-weight:bold" href="engineering_frame.html" target="load">Engineering</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</li>
<li>
<a style="font-size:25px; color:#0ff; font-weight:bold" href="hospitality_frame.html" target="load">Hospitality</a>
</li>
</ul>//closing tag of un order list
<br>
<br>

<iframe src="corporate_frame.html" style="height:250px; width:1310px; border:none;" name="load"></iframe>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So tell me when clicking on "corporate" or any other link the color of that link should be changed until another link is opened.

Comment: can you run the code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes I can run it but I just need css or javascript code for my question

Comment: ok see my answer sir

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
.menulink
{ 
  color: #0000FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menulink:hover
{ 
  color: #FF0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[See the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158473/dropdown-options-to-open-inside-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You've not given much insights as to how you would like to achieve this but below is a jQuery solution. I'm also guessing that you're just trying to show the "active" link on the menu?

```
$("div#navi a").each(function ()
 {
        $(this).bind("click", function ()
        {
            // Reset other link colors to "#0ff"
            $("div#navi a").css("color", "#0ff");

            // Change color for this link to "blue"
            $(this).css("color", "blue");
        });
});
```